# Get maximum value from another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get maximum value of a range with macro. I use the code that you can see below, however always I get a error. I tried everything but I could not solve. How can I get maximum value of A column of different excel?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheet1.Range("a3:d65536").ClearContents
Dim con As Object, evn As Object, yol As String
yol = "\datalar"
Set evn = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set klasor = evn.getfolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & yol)
For Each xls In klasor.Files
If UCase(VBA.Right(xls.Name, 3)) = "XLS" Then
Set con = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
con.Open " provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" & xls.Path & ";extended properties=""excel 8.0;hdr=no"""
Range("a65536").End(3)(2, 1).Value = con.Execute("select * from [Max(Data1$a3:a10)]").Fields(0).Value
End If
Next xls
con.Close: yol = vbNullString
Set rs = Nothing: Set con = Nothing
Set evn = Nothing: Set klasor = Nothing: Set xls = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can anyone knows how can i do it?

Thanks,

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what error you get and where you get it...

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I get this message: [link](http://hizliresim.com/P3yolb) I think, I made a mistake to get maximum value.

Comment: Sorry language is Turkish. The text means 'Max[Data1$a3:a10]' object can not be found on Microsoft Jet database.

Answer (score 1):

Folder objects undoubtedly give the fullest access to file information but the older `Dir` function is easier to use and allows specification of a filename template so I have used that.

I am not an expert on ADODB and have used the simpler technique of opening each bookbook to gain access to its worksheets.

I cannot tell from your code where you store the information gathered so I have created a worksheet "Ranges" and store it there.

I hope I have provided enough comments to allow you understand my code.  Ask if anything is unclear.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()

  Dim ColTgtMax As Long
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim Path As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowTgtMax As Long
  Dim RowSaveCrnt As Long
  Dim WbkTgt As Workbook
  Dim WshtTgtName As String
  Dim WshtSave As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WshtSave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ranges")
  With WshtSave
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Workbook"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "WorkSheet"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Max row"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Max col"
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 4)).Font.Bold = True
    RowSaveCrnt = 2
  End With

  ' ### You need to remove quote
  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path  ' & "\datalar"

  Filename = Dir$(Path & "\*.xls")

  ' Loop for every XLS workbook in folder
  Do While Filename <> ""

    If Filename <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

      ' Open workbook
      Set WbkTgt = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & Filename)

      ' Access each worksheet and identify maximum row and column
      For InxWsht = 1 To WbkTgt.Worksheets.Count

        With WbkTgt.Worksheets(InxWsht)
          WshtTgtName = .Name
          Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
          If Rng Is Nothing Then
            ' This worksheet unused
            RowTgtMax = 0
            ColTgtMax = 0
          Else
            RowTgtMax = Rng.Row
            ColTgtMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
          End If
        End With

        ' Record value for this worksheet
        With WshtSave
          .Cells(RowSaveCrnt, 1).Value = Filename
          .Cells(RowSaveCrnt, 2).Value = WshtTgtName
          If RowTgtMax = 0 Then
            .Cells(RowSaveCrnt, 5).Value = "Worksheet not used"
          Else
            .Cells(RowSaveCrnt, 3).Value = RowTgtMax
            .Cells(RowSaveCrnt, 4).Value = ColTgtMax
          End If
          RowSaveCrnt = RowSaveCrnt + 1
        End With

      Next

    End If

    WbkTgt.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Filename = Dir$      ' Get next file name

  Loop

  With WshtSave
    .Columns.AutoFit
  End With

End Sub
```